# How can I display special characters (like &ndash;) in the TextView?

Tags: android, textview

How can I display special characters(like `&ndash; &quot;`) in a TextView?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `Html.fromHtml()` to handle HTML formatted text into a `Spannable` that `TextView` can display.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the Unicode value, you can display any UTF-8 character. Example, for " you would have `&\#0034;`.

See *[Unicode Characters](http://www.codetable.net/unicodecharacters)* (at *[Code Table](http://www.codetable.net/)*) for more information.

Comment: this is the problem, that i have these characters in such format. and i need it to display. so Html.fromHtml() helps do this

Comment: Happaa...!! You saved me knossos..!! +1 it works for me and you saved me the rest of the day.

Comment: You can also use this format: \u2122, which is the trademark symbol.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml("&#0034")` without slash works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this solution.

Activity class:

```
textView.setText( getString(R.string.author_quote, "To be or not to be", "Shakespeare") )
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="author_quote">&#171; %1$s &#187; - %2$s</string>
```

HTML chars are written directly in strings.xml, no additional Html.fromHtml() is needed. It works fine on all my devices.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a custom method that will convert all unicode from hexa to integer and replaces from actual string.
So that text view can read is as a unicode.
have a look ,this will solve your problem...

public String unecodeStr(String escapedString)  {

```
    try {
        String str;
        int from = 0;
        int index = escapedString.indexOf("\\u", 0);
        while (index > -1) {
            str = escapedString.substring(index, index + 6).replace("\\u", "");
            try {
                Integer iI = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
                char[] chaCha = Character.toChars(iI);
                escapedString = escapedString.replaceFirst(str, String.valueOf(chaCha));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                CustomLog.e("error:", e.getMessage());
            }
            from = index + 3;
            index = escapedString.indexOf("\\u", from);
        }

        escapedString = escapedString.replace("\\u", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CustomLog.info("warnning", "emoji parsing error at " + escapedString);
    }

    return escapedString;
}
```