# Is it possible to load a HTML file into a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

In my app I am loading a html document (contains: the code to display an equation, reference to libraries) into a webview.

The problem is that it still takes some time to load and it does not feel very smooth. I already hooked up a progressbar to make it a little snappier.

I am just wondering, would it be possible to load that html file into a textview? Or can I embed that html code in a textview?

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400987/how-can-i-display-special-characters-like-ndash-in-the-textview/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible :

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHTMLString));
```

Comment: I know that. How would you add the reference for a library and the css there?

Comment: The TextView does not render full HTML. The `HTML.fromHTML()` method only convert a few HTMLs tags to Textview spans. If you need full HMTL support including CSS, you should use WebView

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for achieving this you need to convert Input Stream from your local storage file path and create one String Builder to read every single line from Input Stream -

```
    // "string" is a your html file path
    File file = new File(string);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            strBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        //"total" is your converted html you can show this on textview
        areTextView.fromHtml(String.valueOf(strBuilder));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```