# Android: How to link a local HTML file from a TextView

Tags: android, html, android-intent, textview, activitynotfoundexception

I know there's a lot of questions on here about reading local HTML files, but I haven't found any that satisfy my needs.

I would like to have a DialogFragment pop up, show a message with a link in it, click that link and have a local HTML file read (preferably from the default web browser).

What I have so far:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("I have read and agree to the " + "<a href=\"file:///android_asset/privacy.html\">Terms and Conditions</a>" + " and the " + "<a href=\"http://www.samsung.com/global/business/mobile/info/privacy.html\">Privacy Policy</a>"));
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        //rest of code...
    }
```

The second link which points to the online version works like a charm. The first link should point to a local privacy.html file in my assets folder. When clicking on the first link, an error occurs:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///android_asset/privacy.html (has extras) }
```

Anyone have any tips/advice for this situation? I've tried multiple different HTML files, all with the same result. Am I going to have to use my own WebView for something like this? Seems like there should be a way to ask Android to view a local HTML file from the default browser when clicking on a link...

Comment: Because of deadlines, I had to hack the dialog to show buttons that would trigger a fullscreen WebView (just made the buttons appear to be links). Still wondering if this can even be done (I'm thinking "No" according to samsad's comment). Anyone else get something similar working?

Comment: Here i have answered same type of question [Click here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763846/9552617)

Comment: Here i have answered same type of question - [Click for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763846/9552617)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it won't work because Link is html tag. It will work in webview. Still you want to do this with textview you have customise your code
Try this code :

```
public class CustomLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod
{

private static Context movementContext;

private static CustomLinkMovementMethod linkMovementMethod = new CustomLinkMovementMethod();

public boolean onTouchEvent(android.widget.TextView widget, android.text.Spannable buffer, android.view.MotionEvent event)
{
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

        x += widget.getScrollX();
        y += widget.getScrollY();

        Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        URLSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan.class);
        if (link.length != 0)
        {
            String url = link[0].getURL();
            if (url.startsWith("https"))
            {
                Log.d("Link", url);
                Toast.makeText(movementContext, "Link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (url.startsWith("tel"))
            {
                Log.d("Link", url);
                Toast.makeText(movementContext, "Tel was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (url.startsWith("mailto"))
            {
                Log.d("Link", url);
                Toast.makeText(movementContext, "Mail link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
}

public static android.text.method.MovementMethod getInstance(Context c)
{
    movementContext = c;
    return linkMovementMethod;
}
```

This should be called from the textview in the following manner:

```
textViewObject.setMovementMethod(CustomLinkMovementMethod.getInstance(context));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(readTxt()));
```

//This function will return string which you can set in your textview. And that String have html codes so use Html.fromHtml

```
 private String readTxt(){
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.My_html_file);
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int i;
 try {
 i = inputStream.read();
  while (i != -1)
  {
   byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
   i = inputStream.read();
  }
  inputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
  return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
 }
```

this one is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421553/java-android-how-to-set-html-from-resourses-to-textview)

Comment: this seems to put the contents of the HTML file in the TextView. What I'm trying to achieve is a link in the TextView which opens the local HTML when clicked on.