# how to display special characters in android

Tags: android

I have to display " and \ in app.I have used `&quot;,&lt;&gt;,\`. I can see <> in emulator but " and \ are not displayed. I have seen few posts but coudn't figure out the issue. I have also tried using  `<![CDATA["]]>.`

I have put the above string in string.xml file and accessing it from code to set it in text view. Can someone please suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400987/how-can-i-display-special-characters-like-ndash-in-the-textview

Comment: Use the hexa code of the caractère in UTF-8 or ASCII-usa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want `\"` and `\\` when using those inside strings. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html); it's standard Java.

Answer (score 1):

You may escape those characters using `\"` and `\\`. In your `strings.xml` you'll have something like.-

```
<string name="string_with_scaped_chars">\"Escaped \\ chars\"</string>
```

which will translate to

```
"Escaped \ chars"
```