# Turkish characters are not getting set in the Textview in the custom Listview Adapter

Tags: android, listview, character-encoding, textview

Thanks in advance please forgive me if I am mistaking to explain the problem correctly.

I am working on a Turkish language application .

I have a list view and I have defined a custom adapter for the that list view. I am fetching the data from the JSON web service and when I am setting the adapter after the data is fetched from the web service . When setting the text in text view It is not recognising the Turkish words and printing garbage text in the text view.

A little help would be appreciable thanks again

Comment: You can try this one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400987/how-can-i-display-special-characters-like-ndash-in-the-textview