# showing special character in String in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I am hitting server and getting some data in string format.

in this data there are some special character like - ' . but when i set that string in textview these special character convert into ? .

So how can i avoid this issue ? please help.

first try :

```
  String t = "<![CDATA["+title+"]]>";
        mTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

second try :

```
 String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(getTitle().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        mTitle.setText(text);
```

Comment: Does the data returned from the server contain HTML-encoded characters?

Comment: Convert string to BASE 64 and then set

Comment: @degs no data does not contain HTML-encoded character. data is like nitin's .

Comment: @AmeeJoshi i have use Base64 and then set but no works.

Comment: Can you show code what you tried so far

Comment: @AmeeJoshi i have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: check this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400987/how-can-i-display-special-characters-like-ndash-in-the-textview , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608471/special-characters-android-textview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext @nitintyagi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134184/discussion-between-amee-joshi-and-nitin-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`tv.setText(news_item.getTitle().replaceAll("\u2019", "&#39;"));`

Refer this [link](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) for unicode encoding.