# textview and special characters not showing correct

Tags: android, character-encoding, textview

I have a text showing in the textview which is displayed correctly since years (Productive App), but now I get a nondisplayable Character as result (?)

```
textViewBottom.setText("Übersicht");
```

is showing as

> ?bersicht.

How can I achieve showing the special character correctly and does one know what could be changed ?

Comment: try to add font for the language

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608471/special-characters-android-textview or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400987/how-can-i-display-special-characters-like-ndash-in-the-textview/9401072

Comment: It worked 5 years long now. I didn't do any hacks like the suggested. Any hints else ? Html.fromHtml() did not work for me.